# sudo pip uninstall <package-name> sudo: pip: command not found

Tags: python, sudo, pip

I have tried to uninstall `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu`, but get `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/freeze_graph'`, so I tried `sudo pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu` but get `sudo: pip: command not found`, does it mean that only my user have `pip`? How to fix it?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

python -V
Python 3.6.8

which pip

sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1).

which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

Comment: What are the results of `which pip` ?

Comment: @karel prints nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow-gpu` works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
```